# Wordpress import csv custom fields

Tags: wordpress, csv, plugins, import

I'm working with Wordpress and I need to import a csv file but my project has too many custom fields and every WP plugin I've seen does not work with this feature (or it is buggy).

Any advice about a nice plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried [wp ultimate csv importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/)? It is very nice plugin to handle csv imports. What custom field plugin you are using? Free version support wordpress custom fields and CPT plugin fields. For types, cctm and ACF fields you need the pro version of this plugin.